# Wordpress widget and customize.php not working in Ubuntu16.04 VPS

Tags: php, customization, widgets

I have a WordPress site at Ubuntu16.04 VPS. The thing is, I can't edit my widget area and `customize.php` is not working in one of my WordPress site. I think it's with Google not authenticating my server? We'll not so sure about that.

I tried to trigger the error and took me time to do it cause the error is somewhat doing crazy stuffs at my logs.

So here's the `error.log`:

```
    [Tue Jan 30 11:39:21.584827 2018] [:error] [pid 3369] [client 52.221.193.115:53650] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/edit.php
    [Tue Jan 30 13:29:04.089561 2018] [:error] [pid 5059] [client 52.221.193.115:39534] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2020&action=edit
    [Tue Jan 30 13:29:35.960070 2018] [:error] [pid 5040] [client 13.229.239.178:57777] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php:689\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): thrive_exclude_category(Object(WP_Query))\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(1634): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3222): WP_Query->get_posts()\n#5 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(1704): WP_Query->query(Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(1036): get_posts(Array)\n#7 /va in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php on line 689, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/themes.php
    [Tue Jan 30 13:29:56.859829 2018] [:error] [pid 5038] [client 54.169.161.13:39340] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php:689\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): thrive_exclude_category(Object(WP_Query))\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(1634): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3222): WP_Query->get_posts()\n#5 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(1704): WP_Query->query(Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(1036): get_posts(Array)\n#7 /va in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php on line 689, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php
    [Tue Jan 30 13:36:53.030902 2018] [:error] [pid 5040] [client 52.77.214.37:46626] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/index.php
    [Tue Jan 30 14:39:22.636595 2018] [:error] [pid 6449] [client 34.228.140.92:39682] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/
    [Tue Jan 30 14:40:44.035451 2018] [:error] [pid 6335] [client 34.235.165.206:56194] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/
    [Tue Jan 30 15:14:15.004992 2018] [:error] [pid 6773] [client 54.169.185.149:35062] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/
    [Tue Jan 30 15:14:20.068491 2018] [:error] [pid 6890] [client 52.221.193.115:39745] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/
    [Tue Jan 30 15:14:42.685040 2018] [:error] [pid 6903] [client 52.77.214.37:49346] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant"\n}' in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:288\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(247): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(225): Google_OAuth2->refreshToken('1/glQXffm7BsvKU...')\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php(784): Goog in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 288
    [Tue Jan 30 15:17:36.127515 2018] [:error] [pid 6946] [client 52.221.193.115:34401] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php:689\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): thrive_exclude_category(Object(WP_Query))\n#1 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(1634): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3222): WP_Query->get_posts()\n#5 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(1704): WP_Query->query(Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(1036): get_posts(Array)\n#7 /va in /var/www/html/tipsforsurvivalists.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/focusblog/functions.php on line 689, referer: http://tipsforsurvivalists.com/wp-admin/widgets.php
```

I've tried to rename the entire plugins folder but still not working and no progress. I also did `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` for Google to authenticat well, but no progress. Tell me if any of you guys have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error can be solved by following the steps outlined at [this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652014/error-500-call-to-undefined-function-thrive-get-theme-options-when-trying-to-g). The other errors simply mean your Google Analytics plugin needs to reauthenticate with your Google account, so you need to do that in the settings of Google Analyticator. The `tzdata` package should be irrelevant for this

In any case, you should try to disable all plugins and switch to one of the default themes. See if the error persists.

Afterwards, check out the documentation for your theme (it's called Thrive according to the error log) and activate all plugins required by the theme.

After that, you can try to reactivate Google Analyticator and authenticate with your Google account in the settings.